# HTML to Excel: mso-number-format date format specifiers

Tags: excel

My application exports data into Excel friendly HTML.

With a specific `mso-number-format` value it is possible to show date or time in a local format. However i know only six such values:

- Short Date
- Medium Date
- Long Date
- Short Time
- Medium Time
- Long Time

.NET offers powerful mechanics of defining localized date format with [format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

Is it possible to map .NET format specifiers in `mso-number-format` values?